# PostFix rhyming words finder in Java, functionality and data structure missing

Tags: java, regex, swing

I need to create a postfix finder. following is the code that I wrote. I have to import the entire dictionary of words, dont know already sorted or unsorted words and which data structure/file type it would use. Also, the functionality of finding words by filtering on postfix keyword and then showing to a list is to be made.

```
package hamqafia;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author Zeeshan
 */
public class HamQafia {
    private static JTextField text;
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JButton findBtn;
    DataStructure Dictionary_of_all_words;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        //String[] words = {"Runner, Stealth, Gunner, male, Butter, Old, sar, gold"};


        windowMaker();

    }

    private static void windowMaker(){
        //Initializing and painting GUI components
        frame = new JFrame();
        text = new JTextField(20);

        findBtn = new JButton("Find");
        findBtn.setSize(200,200);
        findBtn.setVisible(true);

        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        frame.add(text);
        frame.add(findBtn);


        //Click Action
        findBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String postFix = text.getText().toString();
            finder(postFix);
            }


        });
    }

    private static void finder(String postFix){
        //Find method to search the words from entire dictionary an show them in the list. 
        // For example:
        // postFix = ry
        //Output: cry, fry, try, dry
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you having problems with?

Comment: I need to load and how to load a dictionary of words, Then I need to have implementation of finder function.

Answer (score 0):

You can make array of String type and store your entire dictionary of english words separating by commas. Yes, dictionary should be in ordered format so that find fast. 
here is some rough idea for finder function

```
private static void finder(String postFix){
     for(int i=0, i<dictionaryArray.length; i++){
          if(dictionaryArray[i] == postFix){
                 ListView.add(dictionaryArray[i]);
          }
      }  


      //Find method to search the words from entire dictionary an show them in the list. 
        // For example:
        // postFix = ry
        //Output: cry, fry, try, dry
    }
```

Comment: It will be very slow and inefficient work if entire dictionary is stored in just an array. dictionary contain million words. Also, the finder function shown here is iterating entire dictionary which is tedious, also finder function is not checking the last letters of words of dectionary, but matching entire word with a prefix which is logically wrong.